# Replacing string with HTML control MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<td style="font-size:1em;font-family:Verdana;color:darkkhaki">                            
@item.ObjQuestions.QuestionText.Replace("____", "<input type='Text'></input>")
</td>
```

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but I guess this is not a duplicate, because all the questions are how to add a control on serve-side. I want to replace a string that I get in my `object.property` in my cshtml View. I want to inject a textbox (or any html control) in place of some special characters.

The above code snippet simply replaces `<input type='Text'></input>` as text.

For e.g.

Acronym of CSS is ##

Here ## should be replaced by a textbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC will by default HTML encode all your strings in your view. You have tell it to output it as a raw HTML string instead by using `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(item.ObjQuestions.QuestionText.Replace("____", "<input type='Text'></input>"))
```

Comment: I don't get this input element in formcollection on submit, is it becoz it's injected at a later stage in the DOM?

Comment: Did you forget to add a `name` attribute for your injected `input` element? Elements without `name` property won't be sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without having to use `Html.Raw` (security concern) is to split the string by the replacement word then combine them together with the HTML input:

```
@
{
    string[] splits = item.ObjQuestions.QuestionText.Split(new string[] {"____"}, StringSplitOption.None);
}
@splits[0] &nbsp;
<input type='Text'></input>
@if (splits.Length > 1)
{
    @:&nbsp; @splits[1]
}
```

This is for string with one placeholder only, if otherwise use a loop instead.